# Is $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n \ln n}$ uniform converge on $\lvert z\rvert \ <1$??

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-continuity

I tried to solve this problem using Cauchy's convergence criterion.

Maybe that problem's answer is not uniform converge.

But I didn't solve it. Please reply why this power series is not uniform converge.

Comment: Hint: This does not converge at $z = 1$.

Comment: Note that the series converges uniformly within its radius of convergence.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I'm afraid you've made a wrong statement.

Comment: @TedShifrin: It is a fact that "any series converges uniformly within its radius of convergence"!!!

Comment: No, @Mhenni, it is not a fact. It converges uniformly on any compact subset within its radius of convergence.

Comment: Whatever moderator is editing my prose, I do *not* appreciate it.